# Tilemaps.SetTile method only partially working when in Update() method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development, tile

I'm completely new (<1 week) to Unity, C# and game development generally. I'm starting out making a 2D isometric, grid-based CRPG and have hit a major wall with Unity's tilemaps.

I have a component which creates a tilemap tile underneath the parent GameObject using Tilemap.SetTile. As the GameObject moves around the grid, the tile should move with it and delete the previous tile. The tile can then create a moving obstacle node for pathfinding (which is working fine with static obstacles).

The problem is that the script *actually does* briefly work, just not for very long. If the GameObject moves along a path 'n' cells in a grid, the script will render 'n/2' cells every time the script is run, then stop working altogether. There's no error messages, freezing or anything, the tiles just aren't being drawn, and I know from logging in the console that the script is correctly tracking where the tiles *should* be drawn.

The obstacle script looks like this:

```
private void SetObstacleTile()
{
    currentCell = obstacleMap.WorldToCell(transform.position);

    if (currentCell != previousCell)
    {
        //set the new tile
        obstacleMap.SetTile(currentCell, obstacleTile);
        // erase previous
        obstacleMap.SetTile(previousCell, null);
        // save the new position for next frame
        previousCell = currentCell;

        Debug.Log(currentCell);
    }
}
private void Update()
{
    SetObstacleTile();
}
```

... and the movement currently looks like this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, destination) > 0.01f)
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, destination, movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

My gut feeling is that it's something to do with how the Update() functions in the character movement and obstacle tiles component are interacting with each other but I don't have the experience to know how close I am to the problem. Any help with what could be causing this would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to run [`RefreshTile`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.RefreshTile.html) after changing for each tile?

Comment: I hadn't! I'm plugging it in at various places using currentCell as its argument and it doesn't seem to be doing much. How would you implement it?